# Creating "fat" Termimal multiboot server LTSP

Tags: wlan, file-server, ltsp

I have 150 mining servers. They all have own ssd drives, and EthOS distribution based on Ununtu. Now I want to crate centralized server without ssd. All machines will connect by wlan and take the image of OS from central server. I have read about LTSP open source project that gives you posibility to make this. But this package are for ubuntu, but OS on servers must be other. How can I make them to boot OS that are not installed on my central server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LTSP is probably not the best option here.  DRBL might be a reasonable option, but I don't know how well it works (if at all) with ethOS.  I would suggest asking on the ethOS IRC channel about netbooting diskless systems.  I would be kind of surprised if it's not reasonably possible (though some distros, notably Alpine, have no way to do it natively), but from a cursory look at their site, it probably is not easy (otherwise they would have info on how to do it there).

It's also worth noting that if you want the root filesystem to be served over the network (which is the only practical option for what you want to do), you should not be using WiFi.  All the protocols Linux supports for this have issues with packet loss, and even if that isn't an issue for you (by some miracle), you will get horrible performance accessing the root filesystem (unless you've shelled out multiple hundreds of dollars on a 6 transceiver AP, but even then you'll probably see performance issues just by virtue of how many systems are involved).